# Vmotion without shared storage

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

ive read that I can do vmotion without shared storage from 5.1 onwards.

Can I do it with standard edition? Or only enterprise?

Comment: So all editions, so long as I have a licensed vCenter server in the mix right?

Comment: No. I said "Essentials Plus" and above.

Comment: got it.  My bad.  I'd like to know how this relates to storage vMotion - should I open up a separate question for that though to ask about the relationship between the feature in the screenshot below and storage vMotion?

Comment: This is how you do what you're asking for. "Change Datastore" is the traditional Storage vMotion that works for Standard and Enterprise. "Change both host and datastore" is a new mode *(in the web client only)* and will work with Essentials Plus, Standard and Enterprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible for [all editions](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/09/vmotion-without-shared-storage-requirement-does-it-have-a-name.html) from ***Essentials Plus*** and up... But it *requires* the vSphere Web Client. You won't see any options to do this with the Windows "thick" client.

[image]

Comment: right. only to add: This is because vmware stopped to develope the windows Client. They want you to use the webclient. And btw: It is announced that in vSphere 6 there wont't be a windows client anymore... so it is advisable to make firends with the webclient...